# I am using the Quickbooks online v3 php sdk and cannot find how I can add a vendor to be associated with a purchase or add the transaction date

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

I see on the docs under delete purchase there is an entity tag but have tried many different configs to add one and it errors out. My code is below and don't know where to add in the vendor info along with the transaction date. I have created a ticket with quickbooks but they haven't answered in over a week.

```php
$expenseData["AccountRef"] = array("name"=>$bank[0]->Name, "value"=>$bank[0]->Id);
    $expenseData["Line"] = array("DetailType" => "AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail",
                                 "Amount" => $expResult->expense_amount,
                                 "Description" => $expResult->description,
                                 "AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail" => array("AccountRef" => array(
                                     "name" => $expResult->expense_name,
                                      "value" => $expResult->iqb_id,
                                     ))
                                ) ;
    $purchaseObj = Purchase::create($expenseData);
    $purchaseRes = $dataService->Add($purchaseObj);
    $error = $dataService->getLastError();
```